# The largest file

Tags: unix, dash-shell

I tried to print the largest file in a directory but I can't explain why I get 768 instead of 726491. $DIR is directory and $ext is file extension. My script should work in dash.

```
 find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec du -a {} + | 
 sort -n -r | head -n 1 | cut -f1

 768     ./subfolder/test.jpg

 -rw-r--r--  1 username  vti  726491 19 mar 12:46 test.jpg
 drwxr-xr-x  2 username  vti     512 19 mar 12:46 subsubfolder
 drwxr-xr-x  3 username  vti     512 19 mar 12:46 .
 drwxr-xr-x  4 username  vti     512 19 mar 12:46 ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`du`, by default show disk usage as block size (1024 bytes / 512 bytes), not in bytes.

If you want `du` to print `bytes`, you need to specify `-b` (or `--bytes`) option:

```
find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec du -a -b {} + | ..
                                                 ^^
```

Accoridng to `DU(1)`:

> ```
>    --apparent-size
>           print apparent sizes,  rather  than  disk  usage;  although  the
>           apparent  size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes
>           in ('sparse') files, internal  fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,
>           and the like
>
>    -B, --block-size=SIZE
>           scale  sizes  by  SIZE  before printing them; e.g., '-BM' prints
>           sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes; see SIZE format below
>
>    -b, --bytes
>           equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'
> ```

---

**UPDATE**

On system, where `-b` option is not supported, use `-B 1` option instead:

```
find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec du -a -B 1 {} + | ..
```

**UPDATE2** In FreeBSD, you need to specify `-A` option to display apparent size.

Comment: I don't know i get this error.

du: illegal option -- b
usage: du [-Aclnx] [-H | -L | -P] [-g | -h | -k | -m] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-B blocksize] [-I mask] [-t threshold] [file ...]
  Largest file .hiden:

Comment: @user3463055, It seems like `du` in your system does not support `-b` option. Then, try to use `-B 1` instead. I just updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Well, now it doesn't show error but it still show 768 instead of 726491. In my computer is right now KornShell.

Comment: @user3463055, What's your operating system. I want to check the manpage of your operating system out.

Comment: It is a server FreeBSD. :)

Comment: @user3463055, You need to specify `-A` also. `find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec du -a -A -B 1 {} ...`. I updated the answer again to add it.